# How to disable front ViewController's view when RearViewController's view is active SWRevealViewController in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift3, swrevealviewcontroller

How to disable user's interaction with front view controller - namely with class ViewController in my case, when the rear menu is shown. With the current code, when rear menu is shown, `bookCleaningButton` is not disabled.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, SWRevealViewControllerDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
  @IBOutlet weak var bookCleaningButton: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
      self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = self.view.frame.width - 80

 //revela the menu if it is not nil
    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        self.revealViewController().delegate = self
         menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
           menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
         self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer()   
    }
  }


func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, willMoveToPosition position: FrontViewPosition) {
    if revealController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPosition.left {
        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    else {
        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
     }
  }  
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should handle this in your Menu view controller rather. The reveal view controller has access to the `frontViewController` and that property can be used to set the `userInteractionEnabled` as `false`.

So, in your Menu View Controller write this this code in the `viewWillAppear` method:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.revealViewController().view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    self.revealViewController().frontViewController.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer()
    self.revealViewController().frontViewController.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

And in the same Menu view Controller add the following code in the `viewWillDisappear` method:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.revealViewController().frontViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    self.revealViewController().frontViewController.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

The above code also adds other gestures, but those can be optional. The main action happens at these two lines:

```
self.revealViewController().frontViewController.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

self.revealViewController().frontViewController.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Hope this solves your issue. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In your front view controller class. Write this code on the viewdidload() method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        menuBtn.addTarget(self.revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        revealViewController().delegate = self

        // Once time - See documented SWRevealViewController.h
        revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer()
        revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer()
}
```

and then use this delegate from the SWRevealviewcontroller in the frontviewcontroller

```
func revealController(_ revealController: SWRevealViewController!, willMoveTo position: FrontViewPosition) {
        if position == FrontViewPosition.right {
            revealController.frontViewController.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
        else {
            revealController.frontViewController.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

this will work up to your expectation....